# how can I select dom with text=? in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

**there is a table:**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>dany</td>
            <td>lucy</td>
            <td>bob</td>
            <td>apple</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

now I want select `<td>lucy<td>` and I want to select it with text
the `td` with `text=lucy`
how can I select it with `js` or `jquery` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna find a `td` that contains `lucy`

Try like this

```
var td = $("td:contains('lucy')");
```

If you wanna find a `td` that  have exact text of `lucy`

Try like this

```
var td= $("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "lucy";
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will select all `td` elements that has 'lucy' as their text.

```
$("table td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == "lucy" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.filter()` , `document.querySelectorAll()` , `Node.textContent` , strict equality operator

```js
var td = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"), function(el) {
  return el.textContent === "lucy"
});

td[0].style.background = "olive";
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>dany</td>
            <td>lucy</td>
            <td>bob</td>
            <td>apple</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```